# How to prevent escaping while making a GET request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, escaping

I'm trying to consume data in my front-end which calls a API Broker and this API Broker calls my API. In my front-end I'm getting JSON data returned JSON with alot of backslashes in it. How can i prevent this? see code and errors below:

Consuming my API in my front-end:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> getCall()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:54857/";
        string operation = "getClients";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //get logged in userID
            HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            string sessionID = context.Session["userID"].ToString();

            //Create request and add headers
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Custom header
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("loggedInUser", sessionID);

            //Response
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(operation);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsondata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return Content(jsondata, "application/json");
            }
            return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

My Api Broker gets the request and executes this:

[image]

As you can see the response content contains alot of backslashes.

This response is going back to my front-end where i receive the following content:

[image]

In this response there are even more backslashes added.

I hope someone recognizes this problem and knows a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to deserialize your JSON string and get the required data? You won't display the actual string of course on your View. You would need to do a deserialization of this JSON string and get your required data for presentation.

Comment: Yes I am, now it shows 3 backslashes instead of 6.

Comment: You could do a `string outputjson = jsondata.Replace("\\", "");` to remove the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by serializing the string to a JSON object and than deserialize it .

Comment: Could you provide any more details or a code sample? Thanks